# stream large data to browser using ASP .net

Tags: asp.net, sql, streaming, datareader

I currently have a website written in classic asp that runs multiple queries against sql, agregates the querues and than pushes them out for display on a web browser. (Paging is not allowed) The issue is that the web server agregates all the query results before displaying which takes up a lot of memory for even one query. The easy fix for classic asp is to write to the response object from a stream.

For some reason I an unable to picture the equivalent in .net without requiring a service on the page of some type. I normally bind to listviews etc which is why I am probably stuck. So if I have a datareader from sql how can I stream that object out to the browser to have a small memory footprint? Do I have to manually call the response object and write out? That seems a little backwards. I think I'm just missing something easy.

Thanks.

Add on:

So what I am looking for is how to progressively stream data from a sql reader to the html page so as not to waste memory. Is that even possible in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea, I woudlnt see a problem with that. Turn off page buffering, and just use Response.Write

Comment: Is there any other way to do it though?

Comment: there are plenty of other ways, but the best one would depend on what you're looking to do. can you tell me why response.write wouldnt fit for you, and the general way you would like use?

Comment: I am looking for other ways besides response.write. I believe one of my issues is that it would break the flow of the page in asp .net due to it writing the information before or after the rest of the page was created.

Comment: you could use `<%= someMethod() %>` which will keep your flow as normal. how large is the data you're returning?

Comment: I forgot about embedded code blocks. That would work perfectly as it happens at the end of the render stage I believe. The data can range from 0 to 20,000 rows where the data can be from 1 to 65k+ characters. If you have any other ideas please let me know.